# PrefrenceScreen basic implementation problem?

Tags: android

friends,
i am using following xml actually i want to draw image along with textbox and then etc controls above and then prefrences below thats why used relativelayout at root level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="First Category">
                <ListPreference
                        android:title="List Preference"
                        android:summary="This preference allows to select an item in a array"
                        android:key="listPref"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/justforme_title_array"
                        android:entryValues="@array/sub_justforme_array" />
        </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and java code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.justforme);

}
```

it is giving me following error

```
01-20 15:07:54.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc/com.abc.JustForMe}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `PreferenceScreen` must at the top of the xml file. You don't need to encapsulate it into a layout.
Try to remove the ralativelayout:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="First Category">
                <ListPreference
                        android:title="List Preference"
                        android:summary="This preference allows to select an item in a array"
                        android:key="listPref"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/justforme_title_array"
                        android:entryValues="@array/sub_justforme_array" />
        </PreferenceCategory>    
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem i think in your code is as you are using relative layout at root level.maybe from these two sloutions will work for you:try only one at a time.

---

1:)remove relative layotu from the root and ramainig code will be same as you pasted here.

---

2:)remove:xmlns: attribute from preferencescreen tag.

Comment: umar i have given tht ption bcoz this attribute only would be on root ele.